# Getting clone() to only work onetime interchangebly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get an image to move over to a separate box upon clicking and then to be removed with a remove button I have in my html. I figured out how to add the image upon clicking it then removing it upon clicking the remove button.
The issue I am having is: when I click the image itself, it should copy over to the right but it should only copy one time and then I must .remove() the image using the button before I can click it again so it appears once more. Right now the image appears over and over upon clicking. I tried using .stop() but that stops the function entirely, I need it to work interchangeably. How do I do this using jQuery?

JQUERY CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#john").click(function(){



var johnImage = $("#john").clone(false);

 $("h2").html("John is in the box");
 $("h2").css({ 'color': 'red'});


 $("#johnbox").prepend(johnImage);




});
```

Comment: Why don’t you store a variable which holds if it’s cloned or not?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: You can put a global Boolean variable which is defaults to false and when clicked set true. Inside click if Boolean is false than do clone other wise don’t do anything. After remove set it to false

Comment: @Volem, Can you type out some code? I am still confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the below code. You should be setting clicked to false again in your remove handler.

Here is the full code after I got your remove code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clicked = false;
    $("#john").click(function () {
        if (!clicked) {
            var johnImage = $("#john").clone(false);
            $("h2").html("John is in the box");
            $("h2").css({ 'color': 'red' });
            $("#johnbox").prepend(johnImage);
            clicked = true;
        }
    });
    $("#removejohn").click(function () {
        clicked = false;
        $("#john").remove();
        $("h2").html("Click John to put him in the Box");
        $("h2").css({ 'color': 'black' });
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked but now when I click on the image again it won't re-appear, it is not interchangeable.

Comment: How did you remove the image? By clicking remove button?

Comment: the #removejohn id is attached to a type="button" in my HTML.

Comment: Check out again. I believe you got the idea.

Comment: Now when I click the image a 2nd time (after removing it using the button) the text changes interchangebly but the image no longer appears to the right upon clicking.

Comment: I got it, the # had to be #john not #johnbox on the remove() handler. Thank you @Volem!